# proplem with brozat/laravel-FCM on laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

i tried to install brozat/laravel-FCM on laravel 8

i got this error on cmd:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\notifications>composer require brozot/laravel-fcm
Using version ^1.3 for brozot/laravel-fcm
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update brozot/laravel-fcm
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - brozot/laravel-fcm[1.3.0, ..., 1.3.1] require illuminate/support 5.*|^6 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev] but these were not loaded
, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires brozot/laravel-fcm ^1.3 -> satisfiable by brozot/laravel-fcm[1.3.0, 1.3.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

any suggestions.

Comment: brozat/laravel-FCM is only supported upto laravel 6. This package is not being maintained and hence has been deprecated.

Comment: As the authorof the fork, you can use https://github.com/code-lts/Laravel-FCM instead

Answer (score 3):

Try this package https://github.com/code-lts/Laravel-FCM It is forked from **brozat/laravel-FCM** and it support's the **Laravel 8**.

Comment: And I am the author of the fork, nice to see it is used!

Answer (score -1):

Did you try **composer require brozot/laravel-fcm --ignore-platform-reqs** ?

Comment: yes I try that but an error occurred again